# Create google cloud bucket and save terraform state to it with the same terraform script?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new to terraform, and am trying to use it to create and configure an entire project from scratch. We're currently thinking about it as 1 google project is one environment.

It seems reasonable to store the terraform remote state inside of a bucket in the project that it is configuring. i.e. have terraform create the google cloud project, create a bucket, and then store its own remote state in that bucket that it just created. That also seems very advanced and potentially chicken / egg.

Is it possible to store terraform scripts remote state in the project that the terraform script itself is creating?

Comment: You would first have to create the bucket and store the state locally and then add the remote backend config. The first step after adding the remote backend is to rerun `terraform init` which will migrate the state to the remote backend.

Comment: @MarkoE So what would that look like then? I'd isolate the project creation and bucket creation into a single file, run it, and then run terraform init again?

1. How would I have terraform ignore all my other files for the first run?
2. If I ran the same process against an existing project, it could mess things up, right? Doing all this also seems like its not atomic, and wouldn't be covered under the lock.
3. It seems this would best be done with 2 separate terraform scripts. An environment create script, and then a deploy / release script. What I'm trying to do isn't possible. Right?

Comment: As Marko said, you basically just need to create the bucket first (using cli, console, script.. whatever). I'm not sure, but you could import the bucket to the terraform state after that, but I don't think it is good, since you can have a problem on terraform and it can delete the whole bucket, so you will lose all states. If you run terraform against a bucket that already has objects, terraform won't delete them, terraform will manage the bucket (permissions and etc), not the objects.

Comment: If you want to "automate" it, you can have a `setup.sh` for instance that creates this bucket and you just need to run it in the first time, or if you improve the logic against it, you can check if the bucket exists and decide to create or not.

Comment: @JuanFontes What does setup.sh to create the initial bucket, etc?

Comment: I mean, it was just an example, you can create the initial bucket using another tool, through the console... But basically that `setup.sh` can have something like: `gsutil mb -c standard -l us-east1 gs://some-bucket`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use terraform to create the project and bucket and then migrate the state into that bucket. But this is a chicken/egg scenario that begs the question, what happens if you need to delete/rebuild the bucket containing the state?

A more sensible approach would be to manually create a master project and remote state bucket. From there you would have a base for a project vending machine to spin up new projects and baseline config.

Answer (score 0):

No - you cannot do this. After days of research, this isn't something that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The gist is you need to first create a Google Cloud Storage bucket either manually, or using Terraform but without a backend remote state.

I am fairly new to GCP, so I took the easy route and created a service account in IAM with a Storage Admin role. I downloaded the service account keys as a json file and renamed them per the video instructions. I found this video helpful: [Authenticate Terraform with GCP using Service Account](https://youtu.be/KilW1B8gxW4?si=-TeJeKcfP2xpDzo2)

Here is some sample code:

```
# main.tf
resource "google_storage_bucket" "state" {
  name          = "<gcs-bucket-name>"
  force_destroy = false
  location      = "US"
  storage_class = "STANDARD"
  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
  #   encryption {
  #     default_kms_key_name = google_kms_crypto_key.terraform_state_bucket.id
  #   }
  #   depends_on = [
  #     google_project_iam_member.default
  #   ]
}

# providers.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.6.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project     = "<gcp-project-name>"
  region      = "us-east4"
  credentials = "./keys.json"
}
```

After doing that, I set up the backend configuration block using this snippet from the documentation here: [Store Terraform state in a Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/store-state)

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "<gcs-bucket-name>"
    # Will store the default.state file in terraform/state/default.state directory
    prefix      = "terraform/state"
    credentials = "./keys.json"
  }
}
```

I had a little trouble with getting the new backend to recognize my credentials until I realized that I needed to set my environment variable in my PowerShell terminal to my Google Account Credentials like so:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.\keys.json'
```

I assume in a Bash/Shell environment, you would do:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='./keys.json'
```

I then ran `terraform init` again, accepted the prompt to migrate my state, and that was that!